# Reading Strings and outputting them to a console Different (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

Sorry for the Title not sure how to word this.

What i am trying to do is make a code that can be only written and read using my program I have already made it so i can write code out to a file, But i am unsure how to make it be read without changing the text file i only want my code to print out to the console or idle without changing the text file at all, I am not asking you to write out the code for me but just how to go about doing this?

```
print ("Welcome Who am i speaking too?")

User = input("Name: ")

print ("Welcome " +User)

Running = True

def FileReader():
    FileName = input("Please Enter File Name: ")
    file = open (FileName + ".txt" , "r")
    #How Do i go about this?
    print (file.read())
    file.close()


def FileOutput():
    NameOfFile = input("Enter File Name: ")
    File = open(NameOfFile + ".txt", "wt")
    Content = input("Type Your Message: ")
    Content = Content.replace(" ", "SP")
    Content = Content.replace("a", "ASDAFAS")
    Content = Content.replace("b", "ASDAKSGDHLHASJD")
    Content = Content.replace("c", "ASHJDGASGDKJASG")
    Content = Content.replace("d", "JHASGDHASLASHGD")
    Content = Content.replace("e", "AKJ:SBDKJASBDASJDBSDBKL")
    Content = Content.replace("f", "KBASLLASIBDJBASLDJ")
    Content = Content.replace("g", "ASJHDVBLKAJSDBLASJDB")
    Content = Content.replace("h", "JHAKSDHKDKSAJDHASJKSHDA")
    Content = Content.replace("i", "KJABSDJKABSDKJBASKJDBASKJDB")
    Content = Content.replace("j", ":AJSDJASDJKAHSDJHSD")
    Content = Content.replace("k", "OAHISDIUHASIDASDHD")
    Content = Content.replace("l", "UIAHSDUIHSADIUSHADUIYSA")
    Content = Content.replace("m", "ASHDUASHDUHASUDHUIASDHIUHA")
    Content = Content.replace("n", "IUAHSDIUHASIDUIAUSHDHUIS")
    Content = Content.replace("o", "AHJSVDJHSVABDJHVSD")
    Content = Content.replace("p", "IASDIJASIDJAISDJOIAJSD")
    Content = Content.replace("q", "LIUAGSDIUGWVDASID")
    Content = Content.replace("r", "JAHSDJWIUCBASB")
    Content = Content.replace("s", "OIAHSDBIWUBDUIB")
    Content = Content.replace("t", "LAJHSBDHBWQIEUBQWIUW")
    Content = Content.replace("u", "INQWOIDNWQIOND")
    Content = Content.replace("v", "OIHQWEIUCBWOIQBEUWQBEWOQIEB")
    Content = Content.replace("W", "OASIHDOIASDOSAHDAISDH")
    Content = Content.replace("x", "OIAJDIWQDBUIOEHWQE")
    Content = Content.replace("y", "POASJDPOQWEOJWQOEJWQEOP")
    Content = Content.replace("z", "ASJDBSOBDOWBQDWIOD")
    File.write(Content)


while Running:
    What = input("What Would you like to do: ")
    if What == "read":
        FileReader()

    if What == "write":
        FileOutput()

    if What == "close":
        Running = False
```

Comment: I think it should be `file` instead of `Read`. same goes for the `close` method.

Comment: drop `"t"` from the file mode. `"w"` mode by itself is a text mode. Use `with open(filename, 'w') as file: file.write(content)`. Use `str.translate` method:  `'abba'.translate({ord('a'): '1', ord('b'): '22'}) -> '122221'`

Comment: It seems the code already prints the file to console (with additional newline at the end). It is not clear what is your issue. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: I want it to read from the file and convert the text when it outputs to the console/idle

Comment: all elements are already in your code: the code reads from a file, the code converts the text, the code prints to console. All you need is to rearrange it slightly differently. What specific difficulty do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Himal is right.

```
file.read()
file.close()
```